# Seeking Modern References on Non-Homogeneous Boundary Value Problems in Hyperbolic PDEs

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

I am currently working on hyperbolic partial differential equations (PDEs) and specifically interested in non-homogeneous boundary value problems. I've heard about the books by Lions and Magnes, but I am looking for modern references that cover non-homogeneous boundary value problems in hyperbolic PDEs. Could someone recommend any recent books or articles that delve into this topic? I would greatly appreciate any guidance.